# How can I remove Unwanted ads on my drupal

Tags: drupal-7, ads

I see some ads on my drupal website. No idea where they came from but I want to get rid of them. Any help appreciated

[image: ad popup bottom]

This one comes up from the bottom of the screen from time to time.
You can minimize it but it doesnt go away unless I close my webpage, and open again

Comment: If you can't diagnose this on your site with access to the source/server, how do you expect us to diagnose it from a jpeg?

Comment: Maybe there also other people with similar ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to Softonic Toolbar not something with Drupal.

I removed all the toolbars or that kind of unwanted programs which I installed(without conscience) then cleaned with Malwarebytes and CCleaner.

Now everythings fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved the problem by deactivating the ad option. To do this, simply click on the "ad option" at the bottom of the ad. You will get a page that mentions different things about the ad. Click on "deactivate" link. It will take to another page where you can deactivate the advertisement. It won't come back.